# DB2 accent insensitive queries

Tags: db2, collation

is there any way of getting accent insensitive results in a select query in DB2?

The version of my DB2 database is v6r1m0.

thanks

Comment: See here for an example that will work in DB2 for LUW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100215/remove-accents-db2/52304253#52304253 . Not sure if it would work in DB2 for i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the case of the column and the value you are looking for.

For example

```
Select upper(lastname)
From myTable
where upper(name) = upper('John')
```

You can use:

- [Upper](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000867.html)
- [Translate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000862.html)
- [Ucase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052925.html)

However, I am not sure if these functions are available in your very old DB2 version. Plan to upgrade!